# How to use two or more autocompletetextview in the same layout?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to make a layout with **two** `AutoCompletetextView`s, the problem is how to differentiate the `.addTextChangedListener(this)` from each one.

I mean an `EditText` can be differentiated by its own `View.getId()`, and do different things depend on this `Id`, but I don't know how to do it with `AutoCompleteTextViews`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `this` to the listener is jsut optional implementation - basically you need to add an instance of something that is implementing [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), and many people tend to do that making the `Activity` class implement the interface. However, in your case it might be easier if you have two internal classes implementing the interface in the way you need it.

Basically you can add listeners even with class defined into the `addTextChangedListener` method call like that:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
             int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
             int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```